# Pub/Sub topics with no schema assigned

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to setup Pub/Sub to BigQuery using the in built pub/sub functionality rather than dataflow however my pub/sub topics do not have a schema assigned to it.

Is there a way to see what the format of the messages are so that I can build the big query table with the correct fields and datatypes?

Many thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic determination of the schema of messages when using a BigQuery subscription. If the data needs to be split among columns, then the topic must have a schema associated with it.

If you want to determine what the schema is so you can create a topic with a schema attached, the easiest solution might be to ask the publisher to the topic if that is someone you have contact with. Otherwise, you could create a pull subscription on the topic and look at a sampling of messages through the Cloud Console subscription page, via the `gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull` command, or by [writing a custom subscriber](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull).